# Find and classify singularities

Tags: complex-analysis

> Let $f(z)=\frac{e^{-z}\sin(2(z-1)^2)}{(z^2-4)(z-1)^2}$. Find and classify the singularities of $f(z)$.

So far I have that there are singularities at $1$, $2$ and $-2$

$2$ and $-2$ are simple poles?

I am unsure how to classify the singularity at $z=1$?

Comment: Be careful about $z=1$.  Have a look at the numerator.

Answer (score 0):

There is no singularity at $1$. It is canceled out by the double zero of $\sin(z-1)^2$.

Comment: does that mean I classify it as a removable singularity?

Comment: Yes. That's the idea.